# running the blender on a single node of a cluster

Tags: rendering, animation, scripting, add-on, source-code

Does any one know how to keep blender alive without doing any job on a single node of a cluster? because the addon (CrowdRender) I used to build render farm requires the access to a blender-running machine, but the node has no gnome-desktop to display the blender.

Also, suggestions of related softwares or add-on used to build the render farm are very welcome.

THANK YOU.